# Slim 3 Framework route error - Page not Found

Tags: php, mysql, slim-3

I'm trying to create a web service here using Slim3 with PHP and mySQL. When I try to connect to this web service, the browser and my postman return "Page not Found"

Here is my index.php

```
$app->get('/teste', function (Response $response) use ($app) {
$response->getBody()->write("Fuck off");
return $response; });

$app->post('/createuser' , function () use ($app)  {
verifyRequiredParams(array('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password'));
$response = array();
$first_name = $app->request->post('first_name');
$last_name = $app->request->post('last_name');
$username = $app->request->post('username');
$password = $app->request->post('password');
$db = new DbOperation();
$res = $db->createUser($first_name, $last_name, $username, $password);
if($res == 0) {
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "User created";
    echoResponse(201, $response);
} else if($res == 1) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Oops, error while creating a user";
    echoResponse(200, $response);
} else if($res == 2) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "E-mail already exist";
    echoResponse(200, $response);
} });
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I know the problem is not the apache because I created a php file inside the directory and works fine.

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks

Comment: What URL that you access? Slim documentation has sample .htaccess https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html

Comment: Have you called `$app->run()`?

Comment: Also, what does `echoResponse` do?

Comment: Hey guys. I'm running the http://webservice.test/v1/teste URL, and I called the $app->run(); echoResponse is a function that I create: 
'function echoResponse($status_code, $response)

Comment: Where is `index.php` located? Inside v1 directory i suppose?

Comment: Yes. It’s inside my v1 folder.